# Titanium Appcelerator Module with FastPDFKit fails to be built

Tags: appcelerator-mobile, titanium-modules

I am trying to create Appcelerator Module with FastPDFKit. I have tested this module with demo code in XCode and it's working. So, I started implementing module for it.

I have done all steps as shown required in document to integrate the SDK:

1. Created Titanium Module. And opened XCode Project created for this
   module.
2. Copied `FastPdfKit.embeddedframework` into the `Othe sources`
   directory.
3. Put code from
   `FastPdfKit.embeddedframework\Resources\Snippets.txt` into
   particular `.h` and `.m` files.
4. Set configurations and select `FastPdfKitFramework` from the `info` tab of the project.

But when I try to build the module I get an error on **`#import "ReaderViewController.h"`** showing `ReaderViewController.h file not found.` I don't know why this error occured only with module development and why it not occured within XCode source of the demo project. Is there any other settings? Please let me know if anything can help me of this anyhow or just give me suggestions about **`how to integrate custom libraries for Appcelerator modules`**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed **Tutorial 2** @ this [Tutorials](http://fastpdfkit.com/tutorials). I have added that *`FPKReaderLib`* in *Target Dependencies* file and *`.bundle`* in *Extra resources* folder. But this time, when I try to import *`FastPdfKit.h`*, I receive error regarding **`File not found`**. So, additionally, I added path in *`User Header Search Path`* in **Module target** as well as **Project**, **build settings**.

> **/Backup/Titanium\ Apps/FastPdfKit**
>
> **/Backup/Titanium\ Apps/FastPdfKit/Classes**
>
> **/Backup/Titanium\ Apps/FastPdfKit/FPKCore**

As soon as I add these path, I receive lots of errors like, `Expected Identifier or ')', missing context for method declaration, expected method body, etc.` And these all errors are being displayed in Library files. Please anyone let me know how to solve them. Event it shows errors on `float` variable types.

Comment: I have contacted Appcelerator Support Forums and raised tickets for this. Recently I have received a response, steps in that was ok to me and made my build successful. But when I try to test it, "Titanium Run" it gives me error for "Undefined symbols for i386: ..." for few classes used in code.

Comment: Titanium guys told me that this framework can't be integrated with Titanium Module. It uses the same class which Titanium uses, "AudioStreamer". I don't know what this means.

Comment: I left the use of this framework. It can't build module with this framework. "AudioStreamer" is the framework used by Appcelerator and so it gives us duplicate error when we use it.